# GoToTop button not working on subsequent uses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, react-hooks, clearinterval

I have a component which scrolls the page to the top. The button works the first time but if I try to scroll down again, it doesn't work. Please advise.

```
    const GoToTop = (props) => {

        const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(0);

        const scrollStep = () => {
            if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
            window.scroll(0, window.pageYOffset - props.scrollStepInPx);
            setIntervalId(0);
        };

        const scrollToTop = () => {
            setIntervalId(setInterval(scrollStep, props.delayInMs));
        };

        return (
            <button
                title='Back to top'
                type='button'
                className='scroll'
                aria-label='Back to top'
                onClick={scrollToTop}>
                <span>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                        icon='angle-up'
                        width='1em'
                        className='arrow-up'
                    /></span>
            </button>
        );
    };

    GoToTop.defaultProps = {
        scrollStepInPx: 50,
        delayInMs: 16.66
    };
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b2ufre?file=index.js)

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: I couldn't make it work not even the first time.

Comment: It was working first time OP updated it with bits from an answer which made it not work

Comment: @TJ Added back old code. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you really want to scroll to top with delay or just want to scroll to top smothlly, but you can try calling

```
window.scroll({
 top: 0, 
 left: 0, 
 behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

And for your code

```
const GoToTop = (props) => {

    const scrollToTop = () => {
        window.scroll({
            top: 0, 
            left: 0, 
            behavior: 'smooth' 
        });
    };

    return (
        <button
            title='Back to top'
            type='button'
            className='scroll'
            aria-label='Back to top'
            onClick={scrollToTop}>
            <span>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon='angle-up'
                    width='1em'
                    className='arrow-up'
                /></span>
        </button>
    );
};
```

Comment: How does this address the fact that the component only works the first time?

Comment: @Vencovsky Doesnt even go up. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n2y8yf?file=index.js

Comment: @a2441918 open your console and try it, because stackblitz is inside another window, it might not work

Comment: @a2441918 and for me, your example is totally working

Comment: Cool buddy. It works now. Thanks. Any idea why it wasnt working with my implementation?

Comment: @a2441918 not sure why, but I think you need to use ref instead of just using it in the state

Comment: @a2441918 was that enough for you or you want to do it using hooks? I don't really see the point of using hooks since it won't be that smooth as using the on in my answer, and also, I think almost all "scrool to top" buttons use that smoth option

Comment: Yup, got it. Thanks

Comment: How do I show the button only if a scrollbar is visible?